# Solving a system of equations $A\vec{x}=\vec{b}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-equations

I have the following matrix:

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}1&2&1&6\\-2&3&5&6\\ 3&6&3&6\\-4&-4&0&23\end{pmatrix}$$

The question on my problem sheet asks me to find all solutions to $Ax=(2,0,-6,31)^T$ by using gaussian elimination.

(I don't know how to write augmented matrices but my "$b$" will be represented by the red column)

$$\begin{pmatrix}1&2&1&6&\color{red}{2}\\-2&3&5&6 &\color{red}{0}\\ 3&6&3&6& \color{red}{-6}\\-4&-4&0&23& \color{red}{31}\end{pmatrix} \stackrel{R_2+2R_1, R_3-3R_1, R4+4R_1}{\longrightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}1&2&1&6&\color{red}{2}\\0&7&7&18 &\color{red}{4}\\ 0&0&0&-12& \color{red}{-12}\\0&4&4&47& \color{red}{39}\end{pmatrix}  \stackrel{R_3 \iff R_4,R_2/7, R_3/4 }{\longrightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}1&2&1&6&\color{red}{2}\\0&1&1&\frac{18}{7} &\color{red}{\frac{4}{17}}\\ 0&1&1&\frac{47}{4}& \color{red}{\frac{39}{4}}\\0&0&0&1& \color{red}{1}\end{pmatrix} $$

$$ \stackrel{R_3-R_2}{\longrightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}1&2&1&6&\color{red}{2}\\0&1&1&\frac{18}{7} &\color{red}{\frac{4}{17}}\\ 0&0&0&\frac{257}{28}& \color{red}{\frac{647}{68}}\\0&0&0&1& \color{red}{1}\end{pmatrix}  \stackrel{R_3-\frac{257}{28}R_4}{\longrightarrow} \begin{pmatrix}1&2&1&6&\color{red}{2}\\0&1&1&\frac{18}{7} &\color{red}{\frac{4}{17}}\\ 0&0&0&0& \color{red}{\frac{40}{119}}\\0&0&0&1& \color{red}{1}\end{pmatrix}$$

Since $$0x_1+0x_2+0x_3+0x_4\not=\frac{40}{119}$$

am I right in saying this system of equation has no solutions? However, the answer given in the problem sheet is: $$x_1=x_3$$

$$x_2=-2-x_3$$

$$x_4=1$$

$$x_3=\text{free}$$

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should add, using \stackrel or \overbrace or something, **what** operations you do at each stage.

Comment: just check if the answer given in the problem sheet actually satisfies the equations. double check if you've written the numbers right and had the calculations correct :-P

Comment: @Timbuc Let me add that quickly

Comment: I'm guessing you made an algebra mistake somewhere? If you look at the third row in the second matrix you have, we see $$0x_1+0x_2+0x_3-12x_4 =-12 \\ \implies x_4 = 1$$ which is consistent with the answer sheet.

Comment: Also, the last element of the second line in the third step should read $4/7$, not $4/17$.

Comment: Alex's comment is right on the money: with that tiny correction, the third line vanishes **all** and thus you have a congruent system with four undeterminates and three equations.

Comment: @AlexS Thanks for spotting that. I will try to redo the calculation. I hope it works out.

Comment: Check your calculation. According to your calculation $rank(A)≠rank(A*)$ system is inconsistent..

Comment: @AlexS Okay it worked out perfectly. Thanks a lot!